# Is it possible to maintain only one revision of certain file in git?

Tags: git

For example, I have a `hostname_ip.list.tar.bz2`(7MB) file which is a compressed file of `hostname_ip.list` which is 80MB.

From time to time, I will update `hostname_ip.list` and compress to `hostname_ip.list.tar.bz2` and `git commit`

So git will keep every revision of `hostname_ip.list.tar.bz2`, which will cause `.git` directory very big.

In my case, I don't need old revision of `hostname_ip.list.tar.bz2`. Is it possible to just keep one version of `hostname_ip.list.tar.bz2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible in Git. But it's not good. `git filter-branch` and some tools can remove the older versions from all the related commits but doing so always rewrites the history, which means your commit history is unstable. It's okay as long as you don't share your repository with others. If many people co-work on such a project, it's definitely a disaster to maintain the branches.

If you are using Github, you could try its new feature LFS. If you are not, you could use other VCS such as SVN to handle large files. But you need extra work to make a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whether your strategy makes sense in git depends on the contents of this large file, and how it changes over time.

**Note:** The rest of my answer depends on assuming that the uncompressed version of the file is text, and line-oriented (i.e. made up of many lines). And that when you change the file, you only change some lines, not all lines.

In that situation, when you change the file, only the *changed* lines are stored in the commit. In other words, the commits would not be very large (at least, compared to the original file).

In contrast, when you compress the file, you are no longer dealing with line-oriented text-based data. Now, every change, even only 1 byte, causes the *entire* file to be stored as a new commit. This is one of the main reasons that the prevailing wisdom is to not store binary files in git (at least, not if they ever change).

So it is entirely possible that the simplest option is: don't compress the file at all.

Comment: Git's xdelta-based pack file compression works on binary files, not just text. What really breaks xdelta is *high entropy data*, such as compressed files. Which means your suggestion (don't compress) is the one to try here, just, even if it's binary. :-)